# Conversion from generic type

Tags: java

I have to get some values from a function that has a generic return type.

I am expecting it to return me either a `double[]` or a `Double[]` but it gives me this error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

This is my code :

```
    private Double distance(Node n1, Node n2) {
    Double d = 0.0;

    Double[] n1attributes = n1.getAttribute("xy");
    Double x1 = n1attributes[0];
    Double y1 = n1attributes[1];

    Double[] n2attributes = n2.getAttribute("xy");
    Double x2 = n2attributes[0];
    Double y2 = n2attributes[1];

    d = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2)+(pow((y1 - y2), 2)));

    return d;
}
```

The function `getAttribute("xy")` was defined with a generic return type `<T> T getAttribute(String key);` and I expect it to return me a `Double[]` in this case.

What did I do wrong ? and how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

**Edit :**

The function `Double distance(Node n1, Node n2)` is called in this function :

```
    public void repulsion(Graph graph) {
    Double forceRepulsion = 0.0;
    Collection<Node> nodes = graph.getNodeSet();
    for(int i=0; i<nodes.size(); i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<nodes.size(); j++) {
            forceRepulsion = pow(K, 2)/distance(graph.getNode(i), graph.getNode(j));
            Double[] oldXY = graph.getNode(i).getAttribute("xy");
            Double[] newXY = {forceRepulsion * oldXY[0], forceRepulsion * oldXY[1]};
            graph.getNode(j).setAttribute("xy", newXY[0], newXY[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug and it works fine until I reach the last node in the loop, then it returns the error.

Comment: Apparently it's not a Double[]. Debug it to see what it is.

Comment: Could you show the declaration for `Node#getAttribute`?

Comment: You can also define the generic T object with <T extends Double> to be more restrictive in your code and avoid such exceptions

Comment: @VinceEmigh The declaration is `<T> T getAttribute(String key);`

Comment: `getAttribute("xy")` is not returning `Double[]`. This is a run-time error, so it is possible for it to return a `Double[]`, but when this line is reached, it is returning something else. We don't have the code, so it is up to you to find out what it is returning and why.

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: Please give the code for `setAttribute`.

Comment: @AndyTurner there it is : `void setAttribute(String attribute, Object... values);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `setAttribute` looks like this:

```
void setAttribute(String key, Object... values) {
  map.put(key, values);
}
```

then you are putting an `Object[]` into the map, since that is the type of `values`, even `Double` is a common supertype of the actual values with which you are invoking the method.

You can see this in the stack trace:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;
```

This is the JVM's internal name for `Object[].class` (the leading `[` means it is an array type; the `java.lang.Object` is the type of the array elements).

As such, you would need to use:

```
Object[] n1attributes = n1.getAttribute("xy");
Double x1 = (Double) n1attributes[0];
Double y1 = (Double) n1attributes[1];
```

If you can change the definition of `setAttribute`, you can make force the array to be a `Double[]` by making `setAttribute` generic:

```
<T> void setAttribute(String key, T... values) {
  map.put(key, values);
}
```

Then you could use your original code.

Answer (score 1):

your method **getAttribute()** returning a plain Object which you cannot convert to Double[],so is the exception

Comment: You don't know that it's returning a "plain" `Object`, as in `n1.getAttribute("xy").getClass() == Object.class`. It could be returning an instance of any subtype of `Object`. If that subtype had happened to have been `Double[]`, it could have been cast to `Double[]`.

Comment: It is a plain object only see the exception    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object` refers to `Object[]`, the class of an Object array, not `Object`. `Object.class != Object[].class`.

Comment: if it is some other type in exception itself we could see what it tries to conver